# Add JSON class folder and import in Java and Eclipse as IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, json, import

I'm new to Java and have searched for quite a time now on the internet to a solution to my problem. I'm trying to add the JSON classes folder to my web app. The folder for JSON classes can be retrieved from this link: http://www.json.org/java/. What I did is copied the folder to my WEB-INF/lib folder and added that folder to my classpath by rightclick on Libraries -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add Class Folder. Ok so far so good! Btw, is this the right procedure for adding class folders? But what shall I type in a new Java class?

I have tried `import JSONArray`, but it is not working. Could you please give the right syntax for importing the JSON classes?

Comment: BTW, after adding the JSON classes to the build path, Eclipse should be suggesting import quick fixes, when ever you use one of the classes. For example, if you type `JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();` then `JSONArray` should be highlighted with a red underline. Right click or press Ctrl-1 when on `JSONArray` and Eclipse will offer to add the import for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fully-qualified class name, which includes the package:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

(And yes, that is the correct way to add classes/jars to your project's classpath in Eclipse.)

Comment: I have tried it is not working. It says that the class can not be resolved?

Comment: Do you have a folder in `WEB-INF/lib` or just the jars? You'll just want to have the jars directly in there.

Comment: I downloaded the folder and there is only classes on it. And I copied the same folder in ´WEB-INF/lib´. Where can I get the Jars?

Comment: Are they `.java` or `.class` files? If you downloaded the source from GitHub, then you'll have to build the project first. Do this by creating a new project in Eclipse and putting all the files you downloaded into it. Make sure the package structure is `org.json`. From there, you should be able to export the project as a jar, which you can then put in your other project's `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Ok created a new project and right click -> export -> choose Jar Files (under java folder) -> marked both .classpath and .project in the right rectangle -> I selected a random destination folder with the filname org.json.jar.  When I did this i got some warnings, shall I just ignore them?

Comment: I just did the same thing, and yes, you can ignore those warnings. They are there because the project was written to be built against an older version of Java. You should also delete `Test.java`, as that will cause a compilation error.

Comment: Ok that was exactly what I did. Thanks Heiler! Really appreciete it!

Answer (score 0):

If you wana to use servlets in tomcat you also have to copy the org.json.jar to lib in tomcat folder. If not eclipse will not give you any error but tomcat will.